# Automatic coloring of cell background according to their numerical values

Tags: tables, color

Assume that we have a table that has values out of a wide spectrum---positive, negative, large and small.

I am interested to know if it is possible to automatically put color on each cell based on its numerical value in a pattern similar to, say, geographic maps (hypsometric tints) or temperature. For example, lower values will start with blue and gradually for higher values you move to another spectrum, say red. It could also be that we start with different shades of the same color.

Here is a simple example of a table that we could try to fix according to what I mentioned before:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|cccc}
    \hline 
    & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
    Alpha & 0.05 & -0.1 & 2.5 & -4 \\ 
    Beta & 7.5 & -25 & 8 & 9.5  \\ 
    Gamma & 200 & 300 & -271 & 68 \\ 
    Delta & 3.14 & 2.71 & 1.41 & -0.008 \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Small off-topic comment: you may omit `amsfonts`, as `amssymb` loads it by default.

Comment: Well, I understand this question is somewhat been answered here: http://bit.ly/2dQLNTH, nonetheless, this solution does not deal with the fact that the first column and row are not numbers, but rather characters.